# Error while trying to access city name using GWeather and gtk

Tags: location, gtk, vala

I want to access the city name and add it to a Gtk.Label. This is how I try to do it.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Or suggest some other way to get the city name?

```
public class Epoch.LabelsGrid : Gtk.Grid {
    public Gtk.Label face1_label;
    public Gtk.Label face2_label;
    public Gtk.Label face3_label;
    public Gtk.Label face4_label;
    
    private GWeather.Location location;
    
    construct {
        get_location.begin ();
        
        face1_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face1_label.label = location.get_city_name ();
        face1_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face1_label.hexpand = true;
        face1_label.margin_top = 6;
        face1_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face1_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
    }
    
    public async void get_location () {
        try {
            var simple = yield new GClue.Simple ("com.github.Suzie97.epoch", GClue.AccuracyLevel.CITY, null);

            simple.notify["location"].connect (() => {
                on_location_updated (simple.location.latitude, simple.location.longitude);
            });

            on_location_updated (simple.location.latitude, simple.location.longitude);
        } catch (Error e) {
            warning ("Failed to connect to GeoClue2 service: %s", e.message);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    public void on_location_updated (double latitude, double longitude) {
        location = GWeather.Location.get_world ();
        location = location.find_nearest_city (latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

This is the error displayed while compiling:

```
[1/2] Compiling C object 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/meson-generated_src_Widgets_Labels.c.o'.
FAILED: com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/meson-generated_src_Widgets_Labels.c.o 
cc -Icom.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libgeoclue-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgweather-3.0 -I/usr/include/geocode-glib-1.0 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/granite -I/usr/include/gee-0.8 -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -w -g '-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="com.github.Suzie97.epoch"' -pthread  -MD -MQ 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/meson-generated_src_Widgets_Labels.c.o' -MF 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/meson-generated_src_Widgets_Labels.c.o.d' -o 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/meson-generated_src_Widgets_Labels.c.o' -c 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/src/Widgets/Labels.c'
In file included from com.github.Suzie97.epoch@exe/src/Widgets/Labels.c:28:0:
/usr/include/libgweather-3.0/libgweather/gweather.h:25:2: error: #error "libgweather should only be used if you understand that it's subject to change, and is not supported as a fixed API/ABI or as part of the platform"
 #error "libgweather should only be used if you understand that it's subject to change, and is not supported as a fixed API/ABI or as part of the platform"
  ^~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-DGWEATHER_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE` to your C compilation arguments. If you're using Meson, [GNOME Clocks has a good example](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/blob/master/src/meson.build#L58).

Be sure you understand why the library authors make you do this. The library API/ABI might still change in the future, and you may have to update your code accordingly if that happens. (For example, there's an open merge request to remove all the GTK widgets so the rest of the library can link with GTK4 apps).

Comment: I did this in my meson.build file.
```
c_args = [
    '-DGWEATHER_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE',
]
```
But it still shows the same message.

Comment: Did you add them to your `executable()` like on line 81 here? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/blob/master/src/meson.build#L81

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot for sharing the GNOME Clocks project. Its really similar to what I'm trying to build and I'll copy a lot of code, hehehe. 

I am very grateful to you.